# Test cases for adding fingerprint in login form using biometric device

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

Can you suggest me some test cases for fingerprint functionality?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? What research have you done regarding fingerprint-based logins? What attack vectors have your read about?

Comment: i am fresher sir. i dn hv any idea abt this.

Comment: I don't understand shortcuts like dn, hv, abt. Can you please use proper English?

Comment: sir i don't have any idea about this.

Comment: As a fresher you still have access to a lot of resources. Just googling "fingerprint login test" returns a lot of answers. Similarly, Google Scholar: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=fingerprint+authentication+attacks&btnG=

Comment: Thanks you sir..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of positive & negative test cases for the fingerprint scanner. You can validate feature(login in your case)based on what is allowed per spec.

- Register any of your fingers(say thumb of your right hand).
- Swipe with a registered finger on log-in from a locked screen.
- Swipe with a registered finger on log-in after the restart.
- Swipe registered hand in an up-to-down, down-to-up, right-to-left, left-to-right, circular motion, wave it above without contact, with gloves on, with oily fingers etc.
- Try with the left thumb(counterpart of registered) with the above scenarios.
- Try with all other fingers of the hand.
- Try with the palm of the hand.
- Try with partial contact of the registered finger - left portion up, right portion up, top portion up, bottom portion up
- Try with the back of the registered finger.
- Try with registered composite keys(ex. more than one finger) this will spawn its own set of scenarios.
- Try swiping with registered or with unregistered fingers when a user is logged in(not locked)
- Try after screensaver locks the screen.
- Try after installing updates for fingerprint reader software or other software.
- Try with hardware updates.
- Try with a mould created from your registered finger.(I used favicol to create mask)
- Slow speed swipe, medium speed swipe, high-speed swipe.
- Try repeated locking and swiping to see if it stops working after a certain point.
- Check-in combination with other authentication options such as card reader.
- Try when the computer is in sleep mode.
- Try after hitting ctrl + alt + del or without hitting those keys.
- Try with the power cord on or on battery mode.

Comment: thank uh nitin sir

Comment: Why has someone downvoted this answer without providing any feedback? That's very unconstructive behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the above mentioned test cases, below are the few  other test cases which are executed by software testing company to test the fingerprint systems:-

- Test the performance of fingerprint system for allowing the valid
  user i.e Time taken by the system to allowed the access of valid
  user.
- Test the performance of system for rejecting the invalid user ie.
  Time taken by the system to reject the invalid user.
- Sometimes valid user is not allowed to access the fingerprint system.
  For this case, test what other way provided to user in order to
  access the system.
- Test the system with valid user finger in different ways say:-

  - Test the system with valid user when finger is dipped with water.
  - Test the system with valid user when finger is dipped with any color or sketch mark on finger.
  - Test the system with valid user when finger is covered with transparent gloves